# Unable to comunicate ROS - Matlab

Tags: matlab, ros-melodic, master, network, ros-master-uri

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS community!
I have a problem...I configured my matlab environment as ROS master and i want to connect external Linux machine.
I adjusted ROS_MASTER_URI inside the linux machine, after that i started matlab environment using rosinit. Matlab sees linux's topics and nodes, however linux doesn't see matlab master... The message is "ERROR:Unable to communicate with master" tapping rosnode list in Linux machine. Could you give me a direction to solve the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367057/unable-to-comunicate-ros---matlab/) by [Dornier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28451/dornier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In addition to `ROS_MASTER_URI`, you must also set `ROS_IP` ( or `ROS_HOSTNAME` ).
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_IP.2FROS_HOSTNAME

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2020-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dornier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28451/dornier/) on 2021-01-12**:
You are right! I ve solved the issue. Thank You!